# JQuery Messed Up Page on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not quite sure how to define this issue. I just started working with jQuery and Javascript and pretty much everything is fine, except for when the page initially loads. I have the page fade in, but it looks like all the CSS isn't being applied until the jQuery loads.

I tried this script in my Head tag, but it doesn't work. Help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('#box-container').hide();
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
       $("#box-container").show();
    });
</script>
```

Whoops: site: http://www.elijahish.com

Comment: Did you try writing the hiding functionality in $(document).ready()?

Comment: Any CSS @import going on?

Comment: Away from the CSS issue, don't .hide() div using jquery, hide it in css, display:none; then show it in jquery.

Comment: @AliBassam - You run into an alternate (albeit less common) problem where someone with JS disabled will see nothing.

Comment: Tried doc ready, didn't work.
Yeah, I have @import, but is this still buggy with Chrome?

Comment: @AliBassam tried display none, but didn't work.

Comment: @JaredFarrish you're right, but let's say JS is disabled, which solution do you prefer, show nothing at all, and display a <noscript> tag, or show everything but without the desired effects .fadeIn() .slideDown() ..etc... ?

Comment: @AliBassam - It's complicated for sure. In this case I think it may benefit from an inline script (as it's show above) placed directly after the element to be effected. There's no best-case or preferred option, it just depends on the situation and it's requirements.

Comment: @AliBassam - Here's another way that's sort've odd but combines both approaches: http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/2/ I'm not a fan of `document.write` (`document.body.appendChild` could be used as well), but what's "best"? `noscript`s aren't always warranted, so it's best just to know what each method's pitfall's are before selecting one.

Comment: @AliBassam - There is a method to resolve the `noscript` issue too, which is reverse it within a `noscript` block: http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/3/ (See just the [Result page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5JpVB/3/show/) with Javascript disabled.)

Answer (score 5):

You should use a Javascript console like Chrome Console or Firefox Firebug to debug your code.

First, you are placing your `script` block which requires jQuery before jQuery is defined:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#box-container').hide();
});
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#box-container").show();
});
</script>

...

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

...
```

So you would see the following (in Chrome Console):

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $(function(){
```

Second, you seem to be trying to run a script which is accessing (in the first block) an element (`#box-container`) before it has been seen in the DOM itself. You could use `jQuery.ready` on that first block, but that could be messy. I would instead suggest you place this right after `<div id="box-container">` is defined:

```
<body ...>

<div id="box-container" ...>
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $('#box-container').hide();
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#box-container").show();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/4 (I use a `setTimeout` for dramatic effect.)

Or put it directly after the `<div ...>` is opened:

```
<div id="box-container">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $('#box-container').hide();
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#box-container").show();
        }, 2000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
Box Container shown on window.onload.
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/5/

And the *coup de grâce* (`document.write` nothwithstanding):

```
<head>
...
<script>
document.write('<style>#box-container{display: none;}</style>');
</script>
...
</head>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/2/

Yes, that is a script that "puts" the style `display: none` into the header, which "neatly" bypasses some of the conjecture that's been thrown around (there's downsides for each method, more or less). There's an elegance to this method (except, of course, using `document.write`, which is icky).

And yet another way, using the CSS `display: none` method:

```
<head>
...
<style>
#box-container {
    display: none;
}
</style>
...

<div id="box-container">
    <noscript><style>#box-container{display: block;}</style></noscript>
    Box Container shown on window.onload.
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/3/ (Just the [Result page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5JpVB/3/show/), disable Javascript to see it work.)

Comment: I like the use of document.write to hide the body - since this protects against hiding the page when JS is disabled.

Comment: I went with the script right after opening the div, however I'm still getting a flash of the divs inside of the hidden one. Do I need to hide all of them as well? I thought that if the containing div was hidden everything else would be hidden?

Comment: @ElijahMurray - You know, I think I accidentally used a shorthand for `jQuery.ready()` in those first two. You can do the same thing with http://jsfiddle.net/5JpVB/4/ (note the `(function($){...})(jQuery);`, which creates a scope and runs immediately inline). Personally, hiding content with jQuery like this is suboptimal, so I'd probably suggest the last two (see the full code in the links) instead.

Comment: +1 for correct spelling (and presumably pronunciation) of *coup de grâce*.  Most people (most Americans that is) pronounce it *coup de gras*, or a "blow of fat."  Probably due to conflating it with "Mardi Gras".  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a case of FOUC : http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/

And, years later we are still plauged! http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/

A variety of solutions are included on this link.

You could also set the style of your content to be hidden before running the javascript that shows the content.  Jared shows you a nice way to do this.

Comment: It's always best to provide at least some of the answer linked to in an answer like this. That page could be moved or disappear and this answer would become much less useful in the future otherwise. `:)`

Comment: I am using @import, but I'm not using IE...Still the same issue you think?

Comment: Yes - FOUC happens on many browsers (the article I linked to is the source, aka very old!)

Comment: @ElijahMurray - The first and foremost answer is you scripts are not inserted correctly, so until you fix that, any solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Might I make a suggestion that you use combination of CSS and JavaScript, rather than one or the other.  I had the same issue using jQueryUI on a site I'm building and found that a lot of these solutions out there would make the contact unavailable to those without JavaScript.

So here is what I did:

CSS:

```
.flash #wrapper {
     display: none;
}
```

What this does is set the `<div id="wrapper">` to hidden only if it is a decendent of the class flash.  So to keep it from being hidden from those with out javascript I add the class flash to the `<html>` element.  So it can only be physically hidden if the end user has JavaScript enabled, otherwise they'll at least have access via the unstylized content.

JavaScript:

```
$('html').addClass('flash');
$(doctument).ready(function() {
     /* Do all your stuff */

     /* When done show the wrapper with the content stylized */
     $(#wrapper).show();
});
```

Depending on your pages time to load you might get a little flash, but it wont be a flash of unstylized content, which is rather ugly.  In my case I had a jQueryUI menu item that would flash the normal `<ul>` element first then the menuUI item, and my `<div>` elements are resized with jQuery so that each `<div>` column is equal hight, but it would flash the different heights first.  This fixed it while still giving accessability to none Script enabled browsers.